# javascript code to c# code visual studio memory shorts

Tags: c#, debugging, memory

```
enter code here
MyDelegate _func0 = delegate (dynamic[] arguments0) {
            dynamic self0 = arguments0[0];
            arguments0 = arguments0.Skip(1)?.ToArray();
            dynamic func0_global = arguments0.Length > 0 ? arguments0[0] : null;
            dynamic func0_factory = arguments0.Length > 1 ? arguments0[1] : null;
            if (_typeof(module) == "object" && _typeof(module.exports) == "object")
            {
                MyDelegate _func1 = delegate (dynamic[] arguments1) {
                    dynamic self1 = arguments1[0];
                    arguments1 = arguments1.Skip(1)?.ToArray();
                    dynamic func1_w = arguments1.Length > 0 ? arguments1[0] : null;
                    if (func1_w.document)
                    {
                        throw new Error("jQuery requires a window with a document");
                    }

                    return func0_factory(func1_w);
                };
                dynamic func1 = new JObject(_func1);
                module.exports = func0_global.document ? func0_factory(func0_global, true) : _func1;
            }
            else
            {
                func0_factory(func0_global);
            }

            //  ;
            return null;
        };
        dynamic func0 = new JObject(_func0);
        MyDelegate _func2 = delegate (dynamic[] arguments2) {
            dynamic self2 = arguments2[0];
            arguments2 = arguments2.Skip(1)?.ToArray();
            dynamic func2_window = arguments2.Length > 0 ? arguments2[0] : null;
            dynamic func2_noGlobal = arguments2.Length > 1 ? arguments2[1] : null;
            dynamic func2_getWindow = null;
            dynamic func2_createActiveXHR = null;
            dynamic func2_createStandardXHR = null;
            dynamic func2_buildParams = null;
            dynamic func2_filterHidden = null;
            dynamic func2_getDisplay = null;
            dynamic func2_ajaxConvert = null;
            dynamic func2_ajaxHandleResponses = null;
            dynamic func2_ajaxExtend = null;
            dynamic func2_inspectPrefiltersOrTransports = null;
            dynamic func2_addToPrefiltersOrTransports = null;
            dynamic func2_getClass = null;
            dynamic func2_Animation = null;
            dynamic func2_propFilter = null;
            dynamic func2_defaultPrefilter = null;
            dynamic func2_createTween = null;

enter code here

 dynamic func607 = new JObject(_func607);
            func2_jQuery.fn.size = func607;
            func2_jQuery.fn.andSelf = func2_jQuery.fn.addBack;
            if (_typeof(_define) == "function" && _define.amd)
            {
                MyDelegate _func608 = delegate (dynamic[] arguments608) {
                    dynamic self608 = arguments608[0];
                    arguments608 = arguments608.Skip(1)?.ToArray();
                    return func2_jQuery;
                };
                dynamic func608 = new JObject(_func608);
                _define("jquery", new JArray(), func608);
            }

            dynamic func2__jQuery = func2_window.jQuery,
             func2_dollor = func2_window.dollor;
            MyDelegate _func609 = delegate (dynamic[] arguments609) {
                dynamic self609 = arguments609[0];
                arguments609 = arguments609.Skip(1)?.ToArray();
                dynamic func609_deep = arguments609.Length > 0 ? arguments609[0] : null;
                if (func2_window.dollor == func2_jQuery)
                {
                    func2_window.dollor = func2_dollor;
                }

                if (func609_deep && func2_window.jQuery == func2_jQuery)
                {
                    func2_window.jQuery = func2__jQuery;
                }

                return func2_jQuery;
            };
            dynamic func609 = new JObject(_func609);
            func2_jQuery.noConflict = func609;
            if (func2_noGlobal)
            {
                func2_window.jQuery = func2_window.dollor = func2_jQuery;
            }

            return func2_jQuery;
        };
```

above code is very big so I cut my source...

i am trying to convert javascript code(js1.3 code) to c# code using expandable object and delegate function
but I met a problem debug memory shorts
if i cut this converted code ,it works but if i tried code all it fails debug like below
CS0041 ERROR
I don't know why this is happened
WHEN I TRY TO debug CODE IT FAILS SOON no information
if code is too long , it would not work ?
or i did some mistakes?
anyone have idea or solution?

[image]

Translated to English:

> CS0041: Unexpected error writing debug information. 'Insufficient memory to continue the execution of the program.'

Comment: You may want to translate that error message into english. Most of us cannot even read that.

Comment: And of course, as always in "convert X to Y code" Questions: The first error was to even _attempt_ a 1:1 "conversion". Don't do that. Write down the requirements - what the code should _do_ - and then put aside the original code and start to implement the requirements in the target language, in the target language's way.

Comment: Images of errors (regardless of the language, albeit, this *is* the English language site) are generally frowned upon. [Why should I not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question)

Comment: I guess it's this one : [Unexpected error writing debug information -- '{error}'](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/misc/cs0041) - which is kind of not helpful without a line number, I'd say. But anyway: I think it's not at all worthwhile to debug this code that looks like it has been intentionally obfuscated.

Comment: The Korean in the error is: _CS0041: Unexpected error writing debug information. 'Insufficient memory to continue the execution of the program.'_

Comment: thanks to reply ,,, 
yes , I also think this kind of code conversion is not good way , but I wanted to try it own myself , and I don't have any other idea to convert js code like c# another way 

but anyway thanks to reply 

if any other people got this kind of error i wanted to ask why it is happened

Comment: and sorry , I didn't know well about this site's rule after this time , I will write question more right way thanks everybody